# PHP const defined

Tags: php, constants, defined

Why does the following code give me an exception saying that my constant isn't defined

```
MyClass::myFunction(MyClass::MY_CONST); // THIS GIVES THE ERROR   

// This is the class..
class MyClass {

    const MY_CONST = 'BLA';

    public static function myFunction($key) {
        if (!defined($key)) {
            throw new Exception("$key is not defined as a constant");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried with

- `if (!defined($key)) {}`
- `if (!defined(self::$key)) {}`
- `if (!defined(__CLASS__ . $key)) {}`

Comment: It is a matter of timing, so to speak. You are trying to use the constant before you define it.

Comment: U need to pass it as string

Comment: While trying to write example code, I was wondering when would you use this? If `MY_CONST` wasn't defined, you wouldn't be able to use it in your first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass it as a string:

```
public static function myFunction($key) {
    if (!defined('self::'.$key)) {
        throw new Exception("$key is not defined as a constant");
    }
}


MyClass::myFunction('MY_CONST');
```

Answer (score 0):

As Daniele D points out, for starts you're calling it with the value of the constant, not its name.

And defined needs a different syntax for the parameter when checking class constants, rather than defined constants. It should be

```
if (!defined('self::' . $key)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the entire class name and constant as a string.

Like:

```
MyClass::myFunction('MyClass::MY_CONST');
```